# Tile Texture If Dimensions of Sprite Are Larger Than Texture

Tags: libgdx, textures

I have a sprite that acts as a wall in a game that I am building. I would like to have the brick texture repeat itself instead of stretch to fit the height of the screen. I tried:

```
Texture lSideTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("wall.png"));
lSideTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);

lSideSprite = new Sprite(lSideTexture);
lSideSprite.setPosition(-50, -100 * (height/width) / 2);
lSideSprite.setSize(5,100 * (height/width));
```

But I am still getting a texture that has been stretched to fit the dimensions rather than repeated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but this might help.

LibGDX needs you to set the wrap on the Texture like you did, but then, you need to make a TextureRegion of the wrapped Texture and call `setRegion(int x, int y, int width, int height)` on the created TextureRegion. Then it's the setRegion width and height parameters that will allow your sprite to draw the repeated texture with the specified width and height.

Something like this

```
Texture textureToRepeat = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(YOURTEXTUREPATH);
textureToRepeat.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);

TextureRegion repeatedTexture = new TextureRegion(textureToReapeat);
repeatedTexture.setRegion(0, 0, WIDTHAFTERREPEAT, HEIGHTAFTERREPEAT);

Sprite sprite = new Sprite(repeatedTexture);
```

And it should do the trick.

Hope it helps

**Disclaimer**: this code has not been tested